# Problems to install silverlight

Tags: rosetta, silverlight

I'm trying to install silverlight in mi Mac pro (retina) with Yosemite bat I can't. I install de package, it says correctly installed but when I try to run netflix it ask me again to Install Silverlight. might be a problem with Rosetta but I dont know how to uninstall Rosetta.

Appreciate any help

Comment: We're going to need more detail.. & more accurate info - The retina macbook pro had OS 10.7 when new, which neither includes nor supports Rosetta. There has never been a 'retina Mac Pro'

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back. What was suggested and worked for me was a full uninstall of Silverlight, a reboot, and a reinstall. You may have to manually remove Silverlight files.

Here's a good explanation of the issue and how to fix it: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macother/netflix-silverlight-mac-problem-installation-says/0b71af78-cb94-46e3-9629-f97c8dda1361